# Where is the adjusted EPS in the 10-Q form?

Tags: united-states, stocks

I can't find the adjusted EPS in the 10-Q financial statement.

Somehow everyone is using the adjusted EPS, but I can't seem to find it. Do I have to calculate it myself and how would I know what was the amount adjusted?

Apple Q2 2014:

Adjusted EPS: [1.66](https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/earnings.jhtml?tab=details&symbols=AAPL)

[10-Q Financial Statement](http://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/displayfilinginfo.aspx?FilingID=9936296-898-278202&type=sect&TabIndex=2&dcn=0001193125-14-157311&nav=1&src=Yahoo) which includes the EPS but doesn't include the adjusted EPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many kinds of EPS](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/analyst/091901.asp) used by analysts, and they use whatever fits them most. Company filings (10K/10Q) include the GAAP EPS, and GAAP Adjusted (diluted) EPS (adjusted to the maximum potential common shares, as opposed to the actual outstanding).

However, special charges and other accounting tricks affect the GAAP results, so analysts "adjust" the reported EPS to what they *think* the actual *real* EPS is, trying to remove these distortions. The company doesn't do it in its reports, since it defeats the purpose of creating the distortions to begin with. You'll need to read through the reports and statements, find these tricks and adjust the EPS accordingly. Or read the analyst's report that's done that (based on the analyst's understanding of the tricks).